# How to insert an icon in MS Word using Aspose.Word C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, aspose.words

Is there any way to insert an icon in a `.docx` file using aspose.words at a specific location by specifying its size?

Comment: What did the Aspose Support Department tell you when you inquired with them??

Comment: In the aspose documentation, I found a way to insert the icon by using the code: documentbuilder.InsertImage("filepath"); But still I dont know how to insert it at a specific location.

Comment: And - **have you** tried to contact the Aspose Support ?? These are the people who are most likely to be able to help you ...

Comment: No, I haven't contact yet. I will reach them.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I have contacted with the Aspose Support Team, and found the solution for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have found a solution to this by contacting the Aspose Support Team.
And can refer in this below link:
[How to insert an icon in MS Word using Aspose.Word C#](https://forum.aspose.com/t/insert-an-icon-in-docx-file-at-a-specific-position/231200)

Answer (score 0):

To insert an image into the document you can use [DocumentBuilder.InsertImage](https://apireference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words.documentbuilder/insertimage/methods/9) method. If you need to specify absolute position of the image you can use this overload [DocumentBuilder.InsertImage(Byte[], RelativeHorizontalPosition, Double, RelativeVerticalPosition, Double, Double, Double, WrapType)](https://apireference.aspose.com/words/net/aspose.words.documentbuilder/insertimage/methods/1)

Comment: This one will work perfectly. But in my case the position in the document to insert the icon will vary, because the paragraphs size above the icon can be vary (which is dynamic).
[How to insert an icon in MS Word using Aspose.Word C#](https://forum.aspose.com/t/insert-an-icon-in-docx-file-at-a-specific-position/231200)
This one solved my issue.